# create a view in HIVE merge two tables

Tags: hive

How can I create a view to merge three tables 
The workflow is like initially one table was created in mysql now this table has been divided to 3 tables and kept in hive
so for that I need to create a view
Initially in mysql one table for eg the table name is Initialtable.
This Initialtable consists of col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
now this table has been divided to 3 tables in hive and I need to merge these tables using a view 
1)table1
2)table2
3)table3

Now this table1 consists of col1,col3,col5
table2 consists of col1,col2,col3
table3 consists of col1,col5

Now I have to create a view so that I can merge these table1,table2,table3 
for that I will put  the non used columns in table1,table2,table3 as null

like create view v1 select col1,col2 as null,col3,col4,col5 from table1 union select col1,col2,col3,col4 as null,col5 as null from table 2 union col1,col2 as null,col3 as null, col4 as null,col5 from table 3

can someone provide a proper syntax to gain this output in hive

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results. It is quite unclear what your data is and what you mean by *merge*.

Comment: What is the primary key of each of the three tables?

Comment: col1 is the primary key

Comment: I need to combine the values of  table 1,table 2,table3

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `table1`, `table2`, `table3` are the three tables which were split and the columns are as below:
`table1: col1,col3,col5`
`table2: col1,col2,col3`
`table3: col1,col4,col3`

and `col1` is the primary key across all the three tables. You can create a view as below:

```
CREATE OR replace VIEW initialtable AS
  SELECT DISTINCT a.col1,
                  b.col2,
                  a.col3,
                  c.col4,
                  a.col5
  FROM   TABLE1 AS a
         join TABLE2 AS b
           ON ( a.col1 = b.col1 )
         join TABLE3 AS c
           ON ( c.col1 = a.col1 )
```